# Replace ADFS during testing/development

Tags: wpf, testing, adfs, adal, identityserver3

I'm researching requirements for a future development and testing environment. The production system to be developed would look something like this:

- Web-API with protected resources
- WPF Client to call Web-API
- On site Active Directory

Access to Web-API would use claims based authentication, preferably by Windows user through on site AD as STS.

**What is the best alternative for abstracting away the AD STS during development and testing?**

Automated integration tests is a requirement, and that again would require the possibility to programmatically setup users and permissions (claims).

I have been trying to set up ThinkTecture IdentityServer3 and using Azure AD Authentication Library (ADAL) from WPF, but I have not succeeded in any working solution.

Am I going down the right path or are there other solutions/practices that are recommended?

Answer (score 1):

For Web API, you use OpenID Connect / OAuth.

ADAL provides this for both cloud (AAD) and on-premises (ADFS).

ADAL works for both those environments. However, OAuth is notoriously prone to small differences between implementations. This may be your problem with identityserver?

Also be aware that identityserver authenticates against a SQL DB not AD.

You could also use the OpenID Connect / OAuth libraries with an OWIN wrapper.

Have a look at the samples [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/azure/dn646737.aspx#BKMK_Legacy).

In terms of unit testing, have a look at [WIF : Replacement for SelfSTS](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2015/09/wif-replacement-for-selfsts.html).

Comment: Thanks. My problems may be due to my lack of knowledge about the different protocols. Still in the research phase. I will try to set up using OIDC.

Comment: Does Adal.js support on-premise ADFS? All I have read out is it supports only Azure AD.

Comment: ADFS 2012 R2 has limited support for Authorization Code Grant only. So ADAL works in that scenario.